# How do I patch the values of a dictionary that belongs to a class with the Python unittest module?

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary, mocking, patch

Let me provide an example:

```
class Devices:
    the_dict = {'apple': some_class(), 'android': some_class()}
```

In this example, I want to patch *some_class()*.

I  cannot mock the class itself (which would be *Devices*, in this example), because that would be the class I want to test in the first place.

I have attempted this issue with patching the dictionary itself, but the mock does not recognize the discrepancy between the different keys and values. For example, suppose I have created a mock called *mocked_dict*, the test does not see the difference between, say, *mocked_dict['alpha']* and *mocked_dict['beta']*. I have also tried patch.dict, but to no avail. I only get an attribute error when using *return_value*.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but consider adding a helper method `mock_device_dict` to monkey-patch the dictionary of a given `Devices` instance:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock


class some_class:
    pass


class Devices:
    the_dict = {'apple': some_class(), 'android': some_class()}


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def mock_device_dict(self, devices_instance):
        devices_instance.the_dict = {k: Mock() for k in devices_instance.the_dict}
        return devices_instance
    
    def test_device(self):
        devices = Devices()
        self.mock_device_dict(devices)
        # continue with your test here ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: The solutions works. I changed it such that the helper method returns the dictionary rather than the entire class instance, but I do not see why it would not work otherwise. I guess it is a matter of preference? Anyway, just to clarify, would I have the helper method as part of the test class (in this case, MyTest), or would I create a separate class to store test helper methods?

Comment: Returning the modified instance vs the mocked dictionary is mostly a matter of preference. Whether you keep the method as part of the test or not is also up to you and how you're running your tests - I personally prefer to do so. When running tests with `unittest` for example, only methods starting with `test_` are tested, so `mock_device_dict` isn't actually tested.